# How to use the keyboard teleop for programs written in C

Tags: ros, rostopic, keyboard-teleop

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to add keyboard support to some programs written in C++. How would I subscribe to that topic and listen for certain keys?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195870/how-to-use-the-keyboard-teleop-for-programs-written-in-c/) by [bluejamesbond](https://answers.ros.org/users/20575/bluejamesbond/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-10-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Most of the existing teleop nodes don't publish key events; they interpret the keybaord events and publish some sort of command - usually velocity commands for moving a mobile base.

If you want to add keyboard support for an existing program, you'll probably have to do it the old-fashioned way - by reading  stdin.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1